# Relation between $\vec{L}^2$, $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{p}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, lie-algebra

I'm trying to prove equation (1.35)

> $$\begin{align}
>  (\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})^2 &=
>  \mathbf{a}^2\mathbf{b}^2 - (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})^2 \\
>  &− a_j[a_j,b_k]b_k + a_j[a_k,b_k]b_j − a_j[a_k,b_j]b_k − a_ja_k[b_k,b_j]
> \end{align} \tag{1.35}$$

of lecture note ["*Angular Momentum*"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_09.pdf) by B. Zwiebach
from ["*MIT OpenCourseWare - Physics - Quantum Physics II (fall 2013) - Lecture Notes*"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/)
in order to apply it later to the operators $\vec{L}^2$, $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{p}$, but I can't arrive to that relation. How would you adress it? Thank you

Comment: What do they mean by the square of a vector? Dot product?

Comment: Yes @SuperfastJellyfish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit calculation is as follows. First, we need to observe that the operators $ a_ i $ and $ b_ i $ do not commute, so we can only switch the ordering of the operators at the expense of a commutator.
We also employ the identity
$$ \epsilon_{ij k    } \epsilon_{ ilm  }  = \left(  \delta_{ jl  } \delta _{ km  } - \delta _{jm } \delta_{ kl} \right) $$

The only thing to do now is to write out the vector expression explicitly in terms of its components, and then shift the operators one by one to get things in the right order.
\begin{align}
 \left( \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \right) \cdot 
 \left(  \vec{a} \times \vec{b}  \right) &=  
  \epsilon _{ij k} \epsilon_{ ilm } a_j b _k a _l b _ m \\  
      &=  \left( 
      \delta _{ jl } \delta_{ km  }  - \delta _{ jm } \delta _{ kl  } \right)  a _ j b _ k a _ l b _ m  \\
      &=  a _j b _ k a _ j b _ k 
       - a _ j b _ k a _ k b _ j \\
  &=  a _ j \left[  b _ k , a _ j   \right]  b _ k  
  + | \vec{a} | ^ 2 | \vec{b} | ^ 2 
   - a_ j \left[  b  _k , a _ k   \right]  b _ j 
    - a _ j a _ k b _ k b _ j \\ 
   &=  a _ j \left[  b _ k , a _ j  \right]  b _ k  + | \vec{a} | ^ 2 | \vec{b} | ^  2  - a _ j \left[  b _ k , a _ k   \right]  b _ j 
    - a _ j a _ k \left[  b _ k , b _ j  \right]  
     - a _ j a _ k b _ j b _ k \\
      &= a _ j \left[  b _ k , a _ j   \right]  b _ k 
      + | \vec{a} | ^ 2 | \vec{b} | ^ 2  - a _ j \left[  b _ k, a _ k   \right]  b _ j  - a _j a _ k \left[  b _ j , b _k    \right]  
       - a _ j \left[  a _ k , b _ j   \right]  a _ k \\
        & - \left( \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}  \right)  ^ 2  \\ 
\end{align}
Now, all you have to do is switch around the ordering in the commutators to get the correct signs in the expression used in the question.

Comment: Thank you!!! I wasn't using the Kronecker delta correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward, so I won't do the entire proof, I'll just start off with an outline. You should know that the cross product $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}$ can be written as:

$$(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})_i = \epsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k,$$

and so $$(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})^2 = (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})_i \cdot (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})_i = \epsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k \epsilon_{ipq} a_p b_q.$$

The right hand side has a product of Levi-Civita symbols with one index contracted, and so using the relation (given in the notes as well) that $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ipq} = \left(\delta_{jp}\delta_{kq} - \delta_{jq}\delta_{kp} \right),$ you can show that

$$(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})^2 = \left(\delta_{jp}\delta_{kq} - \delta_{jq}\delta_{kp} \right)a_j b_k a_p b_q.$$

The delta functions basically enforce that some of the indices have to be the same, and so we can see that

$$(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})^2 = a_j b_k a_j b_k - a_j b_k a_k b_j.$$

The rest of the proof involves manipulating this relation to bring the different $a_i$s and $b_i$s together, while keeping in mind that they don't commute, so $a_j b_k = b_k a_j + [a_j, b_k],$ and so on.

This is a very instructive exercise both in using the index notation as well as using commutation relations.

Comment: Thank you very much